# How to initialize weight between two nodes in a graph?

Tags: c++, graph, dijkstra

I'm working on Dijkstra's algorithm for finding shortest path. I'm having trouble initializing weights between two nodes of the graph on my add_edge function. Because of this I'm having problem proceeding with my dijkstra function. Also I'm not allowed to use vector.
Following is the code I got so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>
using namespace std;

class ListNode; 
class Node {
public:
    int visited, distance;
    char label;
    Node* prev;
    Node* next;
    ListNode* adjacent;
    //node constructor
    Node(char label) {
        this->label = label;
        this->visited = 0;
        this->distance=0;
        this->next = 0;
        this->prev = 0;
        this->adjacent = 0;
    }
};


class ListNode {
public:
    Node * datum;
    int weight;
    ListNode* next;
    ListNode* prev;
    //Listnode constructor
    ListNode(Node* datum) {
        this->datum = datum;
        this->prev = 0;
        this->next = 0;
        this->weight=0;
    }
};

class Graph {
public:
    Node * vertices;
    Node* visited;
    ListNode* head;
    ListNode* tail;
    //Graph constructor
    Graph() {
        this->head = 0;
        this->tail = 0;
        this->vertices = 0;
        this->visited = 0;
    }
    //adjaceny list destructor_helper
    void destructorAdjacent_helper(ListNode* ln) {
        if (ln == 0)
            return;
        else {
            destructorAdjacent_helper(ln->next);
            delete ln;
        }
    }
    //node destructor_helper
    void destructorNodes_helper(Node* temp) {
        if (temp == 0)
            return;
        else {
            destructorNodes_helper(temp->next);
            destructorAdjacent_helper(temp->adjacent);
            delete temp;
        }
    }
    //Graph destructor
    ~Graph() {
        destructorNodes_helper(this->vertices);
    }

    //add node to the graph
    int add_node(char label) {
        //every label must be unique
        for (Node* temp = this->vertices; temp != 0; temp = temp->next) {
            if (temp->label == label)
                return 0;
        }
        //after uniqueness test add node to the graph
        Node* newNode = new Node(label);
        if (this->vertices != 0) {
            this->vertices->prev = newNode;
        }
        newNode->next = this->vertices;
        this->vertices = newNode;
        return 1;
    }
    //add edge from and to the given nodes
    int add_edge(char from, char to, int weight) {
        Node *temp, *start, *end;
        //check the start node
        for (temp = this->vertices; temp != 0; temp = temp->next) {
            if (temp->label == from)
                break;      //goes out of the loop after start node is found
        }
        if (temp == 0)
            return 0;
        else
            start = temp;
        //check the end node
        for (temp = this->vertices; temp != 0; temp = temp->next) {
            if (temp->label == to)
                break;  //breaks from the loop after end node is found
        }
        if (temp == 0)
            return 0;
        else
            end = temp;
        ListNode* endNode = new ListNode(end);
        if (start->adjacent != 0) {
            start->adjacent->prev = endNode;
        }
        endNode->next = start->adjacent;
        start->adjacent = endNode;
        //????????????
        //how do we insert the weight between from and to nodes ???
        return 1;
    }
    //push a node to the stack or queue as necessary
    void push(Node* node) {
        ListNode* newNode = new ListNode(node);
        if (this->head == 0) {
            this->head = newNode;
            this->tail = newNode;
        }
        else {
            this->head->prev = newNode;
            newNode->next = this->head;
            this->head = newNode;
        }
    }
    //pops the tail node from the queue
    Node* queue_pop() {
        if (this->head == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            Node* retVal = this->tail->datum;
            ListNode* temp = this->tail;
            this->tail = this->tail->prev;
            if (this->tail != 0) {
                this->tail->next = 0;
            }
            else {
                this->head = 0;
            }
            delete temp;
            return retVal;
        }
    }
    void visit(Node* node) {
        //remove from vertices list
        if (node->prev != 0) {
            node->prev->next = node->next;
        }
        if (node->next != 0) {
            node->next->prev = node->prev;
        }
        if (this->vertices == node) {
            this->vertices = node->next;
        }

        //add to visited list
        if (this->visited != 0) {
            this->visited->prev = node;
        }
        node->next = this->visited;
        node->prev = 0;
        this->visited = node;

        //mark as visited
        node->visited = 1;
    }
    void dijkstra(char src){
      Node*temp = this->vertices;
      ListNode* LTemp;
      for(;temp!=0; temp=temp->next){
        temp->distance = INT_MAX;
        temp->visited=0;
      }
      src->distance=0;
      push(src);
      while(this->head!=0){
        temp=queue_pop();
        if (!temp->visited) {
                //mark as visited
                visit(temp);
                for (LTemp = temp->adjacent; LTemp != 0; LTemp = LTemp->next) {
                    if (!LTemp->datum->visited) {
                        push(LTemp->datum);
                    }
                }
            }
            //push top of vertices if queue is empty and vertices is not
            if (!this->head && this->vertices) {
                push(this->vertices);
            }
            //algorithm to follow:
            for each neighbor u of v:       
            //not sure how to get length(v,u)???
              alt := dist[v] + length(v, u)
              if alt < dist[u]:               
                  dist[u]  := alt
      }
    }
};
int main(){
    //create a new graph
    Graph* G = new Graph();
    //add nodes to the graph
    G->add_node('A');
    G->add_node('B');
    G->add_node('C');
    G->add_node('D');
    G->add_node('E');
    G->add_node('F');
    //add edges to the nodes
    G->add_edge('C', 'B', 3);
    G->add_edge('C', 'E', 5);
    G->add_edge('C', 'D', 6);
    G->add_edge('E', 'C', 5);
    G->add_edge('E', 'D', 2);
    G->add_edge('D', 'C', 6);
    G->add_edge('D', 'E', 2);
    G->add_edge('B', 'C', 3);
    G->add_edge('B', 'A', 7);
    G->add_edge('A', 'B', 7);
    G->add_edge('B', 'D', 4);
    G->add_edge('D', 'B', 4);
    G->add_edge('E', 'F', 1);
    G->add_edge('F', 'E', 1);

  G->dijkstra('C');

    //free the dynamically allocated memory
    delete G;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is a `Node` ?  Are you allowed to use `std::unordered_map` ?
Edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: There is no point in using `this->` every time. All it does is make the code less readable. Why are you trying to implement a linked list yourself? You could just use a map that maps a node to a map storing its neighbors and the distance to the neighbor. If your professor insists on you implementing your own linked list, at least make a `LinkedList` class to handle everything instead of trying to do everything in the `Graph` class.